# Angular Material cdkDropListEntered is not firing

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I am using @angular/cdk/drag-drop module in my angular and .net core application. I have multiple lists in accordion with cdkDropListGroup option, so that I could move an item of the list to another one.

It works fine in various cases but sometimes does not work, specially when I tried moving an item to an empty list. This is the demo: [example project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drop-lists-in-accordion-ezkkgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I found that when cdkDropListEntered event occurs then the item is being shifted into the target list, and when this event does not occur then item is not being shifted. What could be the issue?

Note: It only works when I open developer tools in chrome browser.

Comment: Having similar issue, did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: Same issue. Can someone provide a solution?

Answer (score 2):

1. in app.component.html replace the below line and code ->

   ```
    <mat-list (cdkDropListDropped)="cdkDropListDroppedHandler($event)" cdkDropList  [cdkDropListData]="chapter.items">
   ```

with the below code ->

```
<mat-list (cdkDropListDropped)="cdkDropListDroppedHandler($event)" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="chapter.items" (cdkDropListEntered)="enter($event)">
```

2. add enter function in app.component.ts like below -

   ```
    enter(entered: CdkDragEnter<any>) {
        console.log('entered');
        console.log(entered);
    }
   ```

and import cdkDragEnter in app.component.ts like below

```
import { CdkDragEnter } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
```

I have updated here "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drop-lists-in-accordion-aizyvk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html" pls check it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is still relevant, but got the same issue in my project. No cdkDropListEntered entered event when trying to drop into empty list. Noticed that when I scroll the page while dragging, angular starts to fire this event. So workaround solution for me was to inject CdkScrollable directive (you should add it to closest scrollable parent element of your drop list), and in `cdkDragStarted` handler force small scroll, like this.

```
 this.cdkScrollable.getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollBy({ top: 1 });
 this.cdkScrollable.getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollBy({ top: -1 });
```

Hope it can help somebody else.